# How do I find the code executed when wp_head() is called?

Tags: functions, actions, wp-head

I am working on editing the header.php file and I am a bit confused.

I am editing the header.php file and I see a call in it to wp_head();

I know that it calls a "callback function" with something like this:

```
add_action('wp_head' , 'callback_function');
```

But I am not sure how to find that. Where should I look for it? 
Basically I need to edit how the  tag is configured there.

EDIT:

This is the full header:

```
<?php
/**
 * Core header file, invoked by the get_header() function
 *
 * @package Suffusion
 * @subpackage Templates
 */

global $suffusion_unified_options, $suffusion_interactive_text_fields, $suffusion_translatable_fields, $suffusion_skin_dependence, $suf_color_scheme;
if (function_exists('icl_t')) {
    foreach ($suffusion_unified_options as $id => $value) {
        /**
         * Some strings are set interactively in the admin screens of Suffusion. If you have WPML installed, then there may be translations of such strings.
         * This code ensures that such translations are picked up, then the unified options array is rewritten so that subsequent calls can pick it up.
         */
        if (function_exists('icl_t') && in_array($id, $suffusion_translatable_fields) && isset($suffusion_interactive_text_fields[$id])) {
            $value = wpml_t('suffusion-interactive', $suffusion_interactive_text_fields[$id]."|".$id, $value);
        }
        global $$id;
        $$id = $value;
        $suffusion_unified_options[$id] = $value;
    }
}

$queried_id = get_queried_object_id();
$hidden_elements = array();
if ($queried_id != 0) {
    $hide_top_navigation = suffusion_get_post_meta($queried_id, 'suf_hide_top_navigation', true);
    if ($hide_top_navigation) {
        add_filter('suffusion_can_display_top_navigation', 'suffusion_disable_component_for_view');
        $hidden_elements[] = 'no-top-nav';
    }
    $hide_main_navigation = suffusion_get_post_meta($queried_id, 'suf_hide_main_navigation', true);
    if ($hide_main_navigation) {
        add_filter('suffusion_can_display_main_navigation', 'suffusion_disable_component_for_view');
        $hidden_elements[] = 'no-main-nav';
    }
    $hide_header = suffusion_get_post_meta($queried_id, 'suf_hide_header', true);
    if ($hide_header) {
        add_filter('suffusion_can_display_header', 'suffusion_disable_component_for_view');
        $hidden_elements[] = 'no-header';
    }
    $hide_footer = suffusion_get_post_meta($queried_id, 'suf_hide_footer', true);
    if ($hide_footer) {
        add_filter('suffusion_can_display_site_footer', 'suffusion_disable_component_for_view');
        $hidden_elements[] = 'no-site-footer';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php
    suffusion_document_header();
    $suffusion_pseudo_template = suffusion_get_pseudo_template_class();
    if (is_singular()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    }
    $skin = isset($suf_color_scheme) ? $suf_color_scheme : 'light-theme-gray-1';
    $extra_classes = $suffusion_pseudo_template;
    if (isset($suffusion_skin_dependence[$skin])) {
        $extra_classes = array_merge($extra_classes, $suffusion_skin_dependence[$skin]);
    }
    $extra_classes[] = $skin;
    $extra_classes = array_merge($extra_classes, $hidden_elements);
    wp_head();  
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class($extra_classes); ?>>
    <?php suffusion_before_page(); ?>
        <?php
            suffusion_before_begin_wrapper();
        ?>
        <div id="wrapper" class="fix">
        <?php
            suffusion_after_begin_wrapper();
        ?>
            <div id="container" class="fix">
                <?php
                    suffusion_after_begin_container();
                ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What tag do you want to modify? What are you looking for? `wp_head()` function should be called in header.php file just before closing `</header>` tag (if it's not there, you should add it).

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż thanks! I do have the wp_head() called right before the </header>. I am trying to edit the content of the <title> tag. But I am not sure where that should be edited.

Comment: But `<title>` tag has nothing to do with `wp_head()` function... There should be `<title>....</title>` in header.php file. You should change the content of this tag (to something like `wp_title()`, I guess...)

Comment: Post your full `header.php` please

Comment: @s_ha_dum just added the full header.php :)

Comment: My guess is that `suffusion_document_header();` generates the title. Find that code and post it. Better check the themes TOS though.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Do you know where that function would be? It isn't in the header.php file

Comment: Try `functions.php`, but a theme could organize code in many different ways. I can't say for sure. I can say: [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

Comment: @s_ha_dum yes I see a line in functions.php like this: add_action('suffusion_document_header', 'suffusion_set_title'); I am guessing this is it, but not entirely certain what to do with it LOL. :)

Comment: There is a function called `suffusion_set_title`

Comment: @s_ha_dum I am not finding that function. Must it be in that functions.php file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9623/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-genadinik)

Comment: @Genadinik: To me it's simple. First, mark where did you placed the `wp_head();`. Now load the page and see the Page Source and see what are the codes it called back. Basically `wp_head()` enqueued scripts, styles etc.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I was able to download the Wordpress, but searching for the suffusion_set_title didn't bring up any results.

Answer (score 1):

since you want to edit title attribute.

- goto functions.php and search `wp_title`, on line 277 you find `add_filter('wp_title', 'suffusion_modify_title', 10, 3);`
- search for callback fx `suffusion_modify_title` in `/suffusion/functions/filters.php`, on line 664 you find `suffusion_modify_title` fx which i think
  handle titles.

Comment: thanks, but my filter.php file doesn't have line 664 :) It only has 485 lines, and when I search for suffusion_modify_title it isn't found there.

Comment: what is version of your theme ?

Comment: sorry, I am a newbie with Wordpress. How do I check the version? :)

Comment: open theme's `style.css` .and search for version